# How do I add placeholder text from the model into a MVC view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html

I have a model:

```
[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
[DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = true)]
[Display(Prompt = "Email Address")]
public string Email { get; set; }
```

I am trying to get the "prompt" to show in the placeholder text of the resulting text box with the following:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, 
new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input-md",
placeholder = @ViewData.ModelMetadata.Watermark } })
```

When I view the generated HTML I only get "placeholder" in the input tag. According to what I have read ViewData.ModelMetadata.Watermark should work. What is the correct way to get this placeholder text in place?

Comment: This sort of thing can be done with `[UIHint]` and a custom template - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14571765/957950) to a similar question.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This solved my issue:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = 
new { @class = "form-control input-sm", 
placeholder = @Html.DisplayNameFor(m=>m.Email) } })
```

The code that did it was

```
placeholder = @Html.DisplayNameFor(m=>m.Email)
```

Comment: But when i use DisplyName and Display attribute, one is for label and another is for Placeholder then this is showing me same for both in Name and Placeholder which i define in DisplayName

Comment: This will double-escape the display name - no problem for "Email", but if you're displaying for example text with accents (french), this will be a problem.

Answer (score 10):

A little late, but if someone is still looking for it...

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, 
new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input-md",
@placeholder = "Whatever you want as a placeholder" } })
```

It's perfect and clean!

Comment: This helped me and it works in tested browsers (Firefox, Chrome, Edge and IE11)

Answer (score 7):

The correct solution to get the `Prompt` value instead of the `DisplayName` in a non-templated control context is the following:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, 
    new { @class = "form-control input-md",
    placeholder = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(m => m.Email, ViewData).Watermark
})
```

This will also - unlike the accepted solution using `@Html.DisplayNameFor(m=>m.Email)` - *not* double-escape the watermark text, which depending on the text and the language displayed can be a problem.

Answer (score 5):

Use TextBoxFor:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Email) })
```

Comment: Your solution will not work in all the browsers (tested in Firefox, Edge and IE11)

Comment: what new you brought, your solution is same as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" , @placeholder = "Username" })
```

Answer (score 2):

I know, i'm a bit late, but an extension method ad-hoc like this one is the best solution imho:

```
public static string UnencodedDisplayNameFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
{
    var displayName = html.DisplayNameFor(expression).ToString();
    var unencodedDisplayName = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(displayName);

    return unencodedDisplayName;
}
```

Usage:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new
{
    htmlAttributes = new
    {
        @class = "form-control input-sm",
        placeholder = Html.UnencodedDisplayNameFor(m => m.Email) 
    }
})
```

This solution won't add complexity (like using `ModelMetadata`) or duplicate labels (like some other answers), and provides full support on accents.

Answer (score 1):

Use TextBoxFor like so:

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LastName, new{placeholder="Last Name"})
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller method that renders view say

`ViewData["Name"] = "blabbity blah";`

then

`@Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.Company, new { @placeholder = @ViewData["Name"] })`

Actually better yet you can do this.

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {              
          NewLogin n = new ClassModel().PopModel();
          n.Company = "fsdfsdf";

          return View(n);
    }
```

`@Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.Company, new { @placeholder = Model.Company  })`

Comment: I really want to avoid TextBoxFor and stick with EditorFor to keep the data annotations and validations in place.

Answer (score -1):

Check out this answers to this question, which has been answered aleady (a few times).

- [Html attributes for EditorFor() in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735400/html-attributes-for-editorfor-in-asp-net-mvc)
- [ASP.NET MVC 3 Razor - Adding class to EditorFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576209/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-adding-class-to-editorfor)

`@Html.EditorFor` uses templates, and so the approach to this problem is using a customised template.

Comment: The linked questions don't address the specific question of populating "placeholder" from an attribute tag. However, using a customized template is a valid approach here - would be nice to have example code here though.

Answer (score -1):

you can use it as follows for the date which will also give you a "datetime" picker.

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString ="{0:yyyy-MM-dd}",ApplyFormatInEditMode =true)]
```